# Computing Maximum Likelihood Estimate of Probability?

Tags: probability, statistics, maximum-likelihood

I am trying to understand Maximum Likelihood Estimation, and am confused by the following problem:

There are 2 slot machines. You can win \$20 with machine A with probability of $\theta$. Machine B has 4 times higher probability of winning, with just one forth of dividend. Suppose you played 10 times with either of machine A or B, and the result was as follows. What is the maximum likelihood estimation of $\theta$?

[image: Results]

I tried to approach this problem by finding the likelihood function, which I got as:

$\prod_{i}^{10} P(A)^{n} P(1 - A)^{1 - n}$

$\theta^2 (1-\theta)^0 (4\theta)^3 (1 - 4\theta)^5$

But I don't know how to proceed from here. I also know that the answer is $\frac{1}{8}$, but don't know how to reach it correctly with the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Take the derivative of the function $\theta^5 (1 - 4\theta)^5$, which is $5 (1 - 4 \theta)^5 \theta^4 - 20 (1 - 4 \theta)^4 \theta^5$, and set equal to zero since at the maximum point, the likelihood function has a zero slope. We can verify that $\theta=1/8$ and $\theta=1/4$ gives you zero slope. Also, take the second derivative and verify that it is negative only at $\theta=1/4$. Plot the function to see what is happening.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You correctly evaluated the [Likelihood Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function):

$$ \mathcal{L} \left( x ; \theta \right) = {\theta}^{5} \left( 1 - 4 \theta \right)^{5} $$

Remember the method is called [Maximum Likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation).
So the step you're missing is the maximization part.

When dealing with Independent events, namely multiplication, is is easiear to work with the [Log Likelihood Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Log-likelihood) (Since [$ \log \left( \cdot \right) $](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) is [Monotonic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function)):

$$ \hat{\theta} = \arg \max_{\theta} \log \mathcal{L} \left( x ; \theta \right) = \arg \max_{\theta} 5 \log \left( \theta \right) + 5 \log \left( 1 - 4 \theta \right) $$

Taking the derivative yields (Equaling to zero for Stationary Point):

$$ \frac{5}{\theta} - \frac{20}{1 - 4 \theta} = 0 \Rightarrow \hat{\theta} = \frac{1}{8} $$

The result above is after few algebra steps and by the assumption $ \theta \neq 0, \: \theta \neq \frac{1}{4} $ which is clear from the results above.